# Wrappers in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, wrapper

I have a question about objects in a switch statement.
I am aware that variables used in case clause must be final (otherwise we get: "case expressions must be constant expressions").
Final on objects means only reference can't be changed, the value still can be changed by other non final reference therefore, we cant use objects in 'case'.
But why cant we use wrappers? They are immutable arent they?

java code:

```
    Integer i = 8;
    final int x = 10;

    switch ( x )
    {
    case x:
        System.out.println("x");
        break;
    case i:             
        System.out.println("i");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Which language is this? It looks like it's Java, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It says Java so it probably is ;-)

Comment: What is your understanding of "Wrapper" in this context? could you give us an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `i` is a reference to an Integer object.

The Integer object is immutable.

The variable `i` itself is a mutable *reference* to an object. It's not a *constant variable*, which must be final and be of primitive type or type String.

**EDIT:** Finally found the references in the Java Language Specification.

First, a switch label can include either an enum or a constant expression, per [14.11: The switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-SwitchLabel)

```
SwitchLabel:
case ConstantExpression : 
case EnumConstantName : 
default :
```

A constant expression is well defined in [15.28: Constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression). The relevant item in this case is:

> Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

Constant variables are defined by [4.12.4: final variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).