# Why does the case statement doesn't take variables?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I know that this is a silly question,but I wanted to know why the case label doesn't take variables.
The code is-

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int y=9;
        int a=1,b=2,c=3;
        switch(9)
        {
            case y:
            {
                System.out.println("Hello User");
                break;
            }
            case a:
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                break;
            }
            case b:
            {
                System.out.println("Buff");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("Yo bitch");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although, I have initialized a,b and c,yet it is showing errors.Why?

Comment: [JLS about switch case construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

Comment: Presumably of performance reasons. By sticking with constants, switch statements can be evaluated efficiently, in terms of statically generated binary searches or lookup tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrappers in switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850261/wrappers-in-switch-statement)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it does take variables, but they must be `final`.

If you do:

```
final int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

then it will compile just fine.

As a side note, having `switch (9)` and maintaining a *list* of `case` blocks, doesn't make much sense, as only one of the `case`(s) is actually reachable.

Comment: Just as OP did with the `y` variable.

Comment: This requirement is documented in the [JAVA language specification, chapter 14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11).

Answer (score 2):

Your `a, b, c` `int`s are not constants.

You can simply prepend `final` to their inline declaration and assignment to make your code compile.

Now of course, you're left with a `switch` statement that compares `9` with other values, which might not be terribly useful.

**Note**

As [still-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2948765/still-learning) mentions, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)'s the documentation.

Comment: I think OP knows this since this is what OP did with the `y` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Proper code might be:

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int y=9;
        int a=1,b=2,c=3;
        switch(y) //here comes y, the variable
        {
            case 1: //here are the cases - numbers
            {
                System.out.println("Hello User");
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("Buff");
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("Yo bitch");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```